# Laravel generating invalid routes

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

i don't know what happened to  laravel, laravel generating invalid routes when i am performing some action like when i open comments box to click button comments modal box opened fines but when i see in chrome developer option -> network its shows me many invalid routes. Any idea why this is happening?

**Please see the attached screnshot:**

Admin is my route Prefix

[image]

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'allow_only_admin'], function () {
});
```

http://projecturl.com/admin/order/

```
Route::filter('allow_only_admin', function () {
    if (Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->is('admin')) {
        return redirect()->intended('user/login');

    } else {

    }
});
```

**This is my ABC middleware:**

```
class Abc {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->admin) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('user.login');
    }
}
```

This is my No_auth filter: which check user logged in and redirect to it user role

```
Route::filter('no_auth', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->is('admin')) {
            return Redirect::route('orders.all');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->is('writer')) {
            return Redirect::route('windex');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->is('teamlead')) {
            return Redirect::route('tlindex');
        }
    }
});
```

**and this is login route:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'before' => 'no_auth'], function () {
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'user.login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm']);
});
Route::post('user/login', ['as' => 'user.post.login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']);
Route::get('user/logout', ['as' => 'user.logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout']);
```

Comment: Can you post your allow_only_admin middleware with pastebin ?

Comment: that's not invalid route. you are redirecting almost all request.

Comment: You are doing something wrong -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: i dont know why its creating invalid and how it is redirecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middlware is probably looping indefinitely with those redirects. I tried redirecting back once and that happened. I'd suggest reorganizing your admin middleware, here is what I use:

App\Http\Middleware\Admin.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Admin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->admin) {
            return $next($request);
        }
       return redirect()->route('some.route');
    }
}
```

App/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',
];
```

Set this as a middleware: in `Kernel.php` add `'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',` then in `routes.php`: 
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
       ...admin routes...

EDIT:
 After you added more code, here are some tips, maybe they will help you fix the problem.

You don't need route filters, remove them all. Use route groups, so admin routes are in this statement:

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
   ... admin routes
}
```

Don't forget to register the admin middleware in the Kernel.php with the correct name (`admin` in my example).

To redirect users to their own area, try putting the logic in the post login route in `Auth\AuthController@postLogin`. There you will check if the credentials are correct (Auth::attempt) and if they are, make that `if else` to redirect the user to their correct place.

You don't need that `no_auth` filter, just remove it.

Comment: Added in kernal like this protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',
    ];  but getting error : ReflectionException in Container.php line 776:
Class admin does not exist

Comment: FatalErrorException in Admin.php line 6:
Cannot redeclare class App\Http\Middleware\Admin

Comment: Did you create the middleware file in the `Http/Middleware` folder? In the `kernel.php` you map a middleware name to a middleware file, so if you mapped that file to `admin`, you set your controller middleware to that nam only. I'll add some more code.

Comment: Your first error looks like Kernel.php did not map the word 'admin' to the current Middleware. Second error looks like you had another Admin class in the Middleware namespace.

Comment: every thing is good but new error /warning This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Are you're redirecting `back` or to the login post page? Try redirecting to a route that doesn't redirect.

Comment: added more code please i am completely stuck in this :(

Comment: I'll edit my answer and add more code, maybe it helps.